# Are one journal editor able to see decision of other journal editor in same publisher?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

My manuscript rejected by the editor of Journal A (MDPI publisher). Then I submit my manuscript to Journal B (MDPI publisher), it rejected again by the editor of Journal B. My question is editor of Journal B is able to see Journal A editor`s decision? Simply different journal editors in the same publisher are able to see each other`s decision?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If both journals are in the same publishing house then both editors have access to the same database of records so yes.

Editor B probably searched the database for your name as a first step and the result of editor A was listed...

Only a guess but possible.

Comment: Let's assume that the editor has access to all the records of all journals in the publishing house, it is really unethical to 1) use external data about the paper without informing the authors, 2) decide about the paper based on previous decision. Some venues asks for precious reviews (although they are in the same submission platform and from the same community) to check if the authors have responded to the review comments.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. Journal B editor asked me ```Please confirm the title of XXX XX, Mr. or Dr.?```. His title is MR. so in my manuscript there are only two students, there is no either supervisor or DR titled person. I replied to the editor`s email. After 10 minutes  I got a kind email that written REJECTED by Editor. So the title of the authors impact to the editor decision? There has to be Professor or DR titled person in manuscript?

Comment: @Younes what pray, are precious reviews?

Comment: @SolarMike typo for "previous reviews", perchance?

Answer (score 4):

**No**. You can see the decisions of papers submitted to your journal, but not to other journals, even if they are by the same publisher. An employee of the publisher with access to both journals might be able to, but not the members of the editorial board.

Comment: I have got an email from an editor: ```Other
MDPI journal editors are able to see the decision of this manuscript.```

Comment: @Furqat would be shockingly unusual, and given the ambiguities in that sentence, I would not be surprised if your interpretation of it is incorrect.

Comment: @Furqat, an editor X (and all members of the editorial board) with all the duties he/she has (most likely to be a professor, teaching, writing papers/proposals, reviewing papers/proposals, supervising students, etc.) and the tens of papers he/she receives. You think, he/she will search for your submission (that will have different id) if it is rejected from another journal in the same publishing platform (which has a very very low probability).

Comment: @Furqat, If he/she has so much free time and does this, he/she is a very bad editor (which I don't think so) if he/she considers the decision of another journal to make a decision about your paper. Your paper is rejected only because it is not good enough for the journal and you have definitely received an email listing the reasons. If it is about the quality, then work on it and resubmit it (if recommended). Otherwise, your paper is out of scope and you need to submit it to the right journal

Comment: @Furqat I joined MDPI and have an insider's view now, so I can interpret that sentence better. Chances are, by "MDPI journal editors", the sentence is referring to MDPI employees that handle the journal - so yeah, the original answer I wrote is correct, an employee of the publisher can see the decision but not members of the editorial board.